# Movie featuring a De Lorean - NOT Back to the Future

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember a movie (possibly a TV show, but more likely a movie), I think from around the 80's, which featured a De Lorean.  It's *not* one of the Back to the Future movies, nor does it make any reference to them.  It is fiction, so not one of the several documentaries about John De Lorean or the car itself.  The car is definitely featured in the movie, not just sitting in the background (e.g. the one in Scarface).  The De Lorean is definitely the "hero car" in this movie, the main characters drive it, it is involved in a chase if I recall.  The movie holds something of a cult-classic status, though it's obviously less well-known than BTTF.  I feel like there was a sci-fi element to the movie, though it was set in present day for when it was released.

Comment: "I feel like there was a sci-fi element" isn't enough to make this on-topic. Do you remember *anything* about the supposed SF content?

Comment: @RobertColumbia The thing that kept coming to my head was Flash Gordon - I know that's not it, but it was something of about the same level of production.

Comment: The first thing I thought of was the Car in "The Last Starfighter". It has a Delorian look, that has been heavily customized. https://starcarcentral.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/starcar2.jpg But I don't know if it was actually a Delorian.  The movie is a cult classic, it is involved in a chase, But it is only featured in about 1/4th-1/3rd? of the movie

Comment: @NJohnny Ooh!  I think that might be it.  Yeah, looking at it now, it's probably not actually a DeLorean (which is likely why it wasn't on the IMCDB list and why I couldn't find it searching for any variation of "Movies featuring a DeLorean"), but definitely very similar, and close enough to make me remember it as one.  If you want to make that an answer, it's probably what I was thinking of.  Thanks.

Comment: Same movie, but COMPLETELY different question. Not a duplicate.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Duplicate policy on story id is to close to the same work, the fact that the questions are “entirely different” is irrelevant to that.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Excuse me, what?  How does that make any sense?  Just because two questions can have the same answer doesn't make them the same question.  That policy is absurd.  There's no way I would've been able to find the answer by looking at that question because they have nothing in common.  (I don't especially care since I got the answer anyhow, but marking this as a duplicate makes no sense whatsoever.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's to group questions together with the same answer so that the different descriptions and information are kept together to better help people in the future. Duplicate closure is not a bad thing and it is not meant to say "you should have looked here", in fact we don't even close on id questions until both have an "accepted answer". It's merely just for housekeeping reasons and like I said to keep the common information together. If you'd like I could dig up a relevant meta for further reading? But again ___it is not a bad thing___.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibly the car driven by the character "Centauri" from the movie "The Last Starfighter"

[image: Car 1]

[image: Car 2]

Its hard to be sure if it IS a DeLorean, but it looks like it could be a heavily modified one.

It is involved in at least one chase scene.

The movie is a Cult classic.

But the car plays only a minor role in the movie. Usually shown when "Centauri" is on screen.

Comment: It's definitely a DeLorean-inspired vehicle.

Comment: Yeah, I 'm going to go ahead and accept this.  It's certainly close enough to make one think of a DeLorean, and might even be one underneath.  It's a movie I know I saw from around the right time period, it was in a chase scene, and to whoever down-voted this question as off-topic, yes it is indeed a SciFi cult-classic.  Maybe would've been better to ask in Movies & TV, but hey, it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a DeLorean, it's a made-for-the-film custom vehicle that was produced about a year before the DMC DeLorean hit the market. It was apparently a refit of one of the vehicles used in the film Blade Runner; https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Spinner

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, I agree it's definitely not an actual DeLorean, which is why my search turned up nothing.  I'm pretty sure this is the movie I was thinking of, however.  Now that you mention the timing though - is it possible the actual DeLorean was inspired by this car (or the Blade Runner version of it) rather than the other way around?  It is remarkably similar...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Gull-wing doors have been around for decades. It's unlikely that one was inspired by the other. The timescales are too close.

Comment: To my eye, this car resembles a DeLorean much more than in just the gull-wing doors. It's an angular design, all planes and straight creases, with a stainless-steel appearance. Even the spoilers on the back bring to mind the boosters (or whatever they were) on Doc's time machine.